# Parceler and Lombok not working together?

Tags: android, lombok, parceler

For my android app I use the parceler library and the lombok library.

These are the annotations of my class:

```
@Table
@ToString
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Parcel
public class MyClass {
```

However, during gradle build, Parceler complains that there is no default empty constructor. So does this mean it doesn't recognize the `@NoArgsConstructor` annotation and these two simply won't work together? Because e.g. SugarORM has no probs with it. Or am I just missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This gets into how Lombok adds code to your class.  Lombok uses a [known trick](http://notatube.blogspot.com/2010/11/project-lombok-trick-explained.html) in the Java annotation processor to add code to your class.  This added code is not visible to Parceler during the annotation processor round and makes the added no-args constructor unknown to Parceler.

I'd recommend adding the no-args constructor manually, annotating the existing constructor with `@ParcelConstructor` (I assume you have one) or consider using the Lombok fork [Hrisey](https://github.com/mg6maciej/hrisey) that has an `@Parcelable` annotation.

We had an issue/question about this recently: https://github.com/johncarl81/parceler/issues/177

Comment: Nice to see someone from the "parcelers" directly ;D Yeah I guessed that. I made a no args constructor myself by now. Do you recommend Hrisey? It would indeed combine the use of two libraries into one.

Comment: I haven't used it myself, but it looks like it would do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** Initial solution failed after I did some cleaning, also, it didn't work with Proguard. See updated solution below.

To solve this problem, I had to create my own custom annotation processor. The idea of this processor was to ensure processor order for the processors used by Lombok and Parceler.

Here are the steps I followed to resolve this problem:

**Step 1**

Create a new Java Module under the root project. Call it any name, for example `parceler-lombok`, use any class name/package of your choice.

**Step 2**

Add lombok and Parceler annotation classes as dependency to the new module, and set source compatibility.

```
//File: parceler-lombok/build.gradle
apply plugin: 'java'
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.16'
    compile 'org.parceler:parceler:1.1.9'
}

sourceCompatibility = "1.7"
targetCompatibility = "1.7"
```

**Step 3**

Create the following directory in your main source folder for the module: *src/main/resources/META-INF/services*

**Step 4**

Create a file called `javax.annotation.processing.Processor` inside the directory above.

**Step 5**

Edit the file, and add the following lines.

```
lombok.launch.AnnotationProcessorHider$AnnotationProcessor
lombok.launch.AnnotationProcessorHider$ClaimingProcessor
org.parceler.ParcelAnnotationProcessor
```

This is a declaration of all the annotation processors available in your module. The order shows that Lombok annotation processors should be loaded before parceler's

**Step 6**

Now that we have our "custom annotation processor", go back to your main app module, in your build.gradle file for app, do the following:

- Remove lombok dependency (annotatorProcessor, provided or compile) directive
- Remove the parceler annotationProcessor dependency (i.e. `org.parceler:parceler`), leave the API dependency as-is.
- Now add your custom annotation processor as a dependency
- Finally, ensure Java 1.7 compatibility

See snippets below :

```
//File: app/build.gradle
android {
  //...
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
  //...
}

dependencies {
    // ...
    //Remove these ones
    //provided 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.16'
    //annotationProcessor 'org.parceler:parceler:1.1.9'

    //leave parceler API
    compile 'org.parceler:parceler-api:1.1.9'
    provided project(':parceler-lombok')
}
```

Using provided ensures that the annotation processor classes are not bundled with your app.

---

The following articles were very helpful:

- https://medium.com/@emmasuzuki/annotation-processor-101-your-first-custom-annotation-a3db9ae48046
- https://academy.realm.io/posts/360andev-ryan-harter-eliminate-boilerplate/

Comment: The initial solution failed when I tried using proguard. After hours of research, I was able to solve the issue. See new solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use @ParcelFactory on a static method building an empty object:

```
@Builder
public class MyClass {
    @ParcelFactory
    static MyClass fromParcel() {
        return builder().build();
    }
}
```

This trick can ben used with Jackson and other libraries allowing you to annotate static factory methods in addition to constructors.