# Parceler: Unable to find read/write generator for type RealmList<backend.model.Invitation> for backend.model.ProjectInfo#invitations

Tags: java, android, realm, parceler

I am using [Parceler](https://github.com/johncarl81/parceler/) for [FragmentArgs](https://github.com/sockeqwe/fragmentargs) with [RealmObjects](https://realm.io/) (and [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/)) and getting the following build error.

```
Error:(73, 70) error: Parceler: Unable to find read/write generator for type io.realm.RealmList<backend.model.Invitation> for backend.model.ProjectInfo#invitations
```

My class ProjectInfo looks like this

```
@Parcel(implementations = {ProjectInfoRealmProxy.class}, value = Parcel.Serialization.BEAN, analyze = {ProjectInfo.class})
public class ProjectInfo extends RealmObject
{
@Getter @Setter @PrimaryKey long projectId;

@ParcelPropertyConverter(RealmListParcelConverter.class) @Getter @Setter @Ignore RealmList<Invitation> invitations;
@ParcelPropertyConverter(RealmListParcelConverter.class) @Getter @Setter         RealmList<Submission> submissions;
}
```

The Classes Submission and Invitation are both quite simple data structures that also extend `RealmObject`

The class `RealmListParcelConverter` looks like this:

```
public class RealmListParcelConverter implements TypeRangeParcelConverter<RealmList<? extends RealmObject>, RealmList<? extends RealmObject>>
{
    private static final int NULL = -1;

    @Override
    public void toParcel(RealmList<? extends RealmObject> input, Parcel parcel)
    {
        parcel.writeInt(input == null ? NULL : input.size());
        if(input != null)
        {
            for(RealmObject item : input)
            {
                parcel.writeParcelable(Parcels.wrap(item), 0);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public RealmList fromParcel(Parcel parcel)
    {
        int       size = parcel.readInt();
        RealmList list = new RealmList();
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            Parcelable parcelable = parcel.readParcelable(getClass().getClassLoader());
            list.add((RealmObject) Parcels.unwrap(parcelable));
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

**What am i doing wrong?**

## UPDATE 1

Invitation class

```
@Parcel(implementations = {InvitationRealmProxy.class}, value = Parcel.Serialization.BEAN, analyze = {Invitation.class})
public class Invitation extends RealmObject
{
    @Getter @Setter long    accountId;
    @Getter @Setter long    projectId;
    @Getter @Setter boolean declined;
    @Getter @Setter String  name;
    public Invitation() {}
}
```

And the Submission class

```
@Parcel(implementations = {SubmissionRealmProxy.class}, value = Parcel.Serialization.BEAN, analyze = {Submission.class})
public class Submission extends RealmObject
{
    @Getter @Setter @PrimaryKey long    id;
    @Getter @Setter             long    creator;
    @Getter @Setter             float   length;

    public Submission() {}

}
```

## UPDATE2

This happens only if i use

```
@Parcel(implementations = {ProjectInfoRealmProxy.class}, value = Parcel.Serialization.BEAN, analyze = {ProjectInfo.class})
```

If i use a simple

```
@Parcel
```

It crashes during runtime with the crash

```
org.parceler.ParcelerRuntimeException: Unable to find generated Parcelable class for io.realm.ProjectInfoRealmProxy
```

## UPDATE 3

I am using the parcel within the @Args annotation like this

```
@Arg(bundler = ParcelerArgsBundler.class) ProjectInfo projectInfo;
```

Comment: Personally I'm not sure why you're sending a parcelled unmanaged object rather than just the `projectId` and then requery it in the fragment. Otherwise, good question and I'm not sure why you're getting the error, other than that it probably has to do with the `@Ignore` annotation

Comment: What is `Invitation` class?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce well, thats a great question :) and see updated question

Comment: I'm asking because unless you're sending objects to another application directly (which seems rather odd), you generally don't have to parcel entire RealmObjects unless you detach them from the Realm, which you generally don't have to do unless you want to send them through GSON.

Comment: Also, please add the code where you actually add the object to the Bundle with `Parcels.wrap()` and stuff.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37543057/parceler-and-lombok-not-working-together

Comment: Ah. There's no way I would have figured that out, sorry.